# Perl OO Superclass variables not binding to subclass object when printing

Tags: perl

I am doing a Perl OO example (mainly to reacquaint myself with Perl) and using
inheritance, it seems that the SUPER works in the subclass when calling the superclass constructor and that 
the superclass variables don't bind to the subclass object.  Why would this be?

```
################################################
## Package : Person                          ##
################################################
package Person;

################################################
## Constructor                                ##
################################################
sub new(){

    my $class = shift;
    my $data = {};
    $data->{'firstName'} = shift;
    $data->{'secondName'} = shift;  
    bless $data, $class; 
    #bless $data, "Person"; #hack
    return $data;
}

################################################
## Getter Methods                            ##
################################################

sub getFirstName(){
  my $data = shift;
  return $data->{'firstName'};
}

sub getSecondName(){
  my $data = shift;
  return $data->{'secondName'};
}

################################################
## Setter methods                            ##
################################################

sub setFirstName($){
  my $data = shift;
  $data->{'firstName'} = shift;
}

sub setSecondName($){
  my $data = shift;
  $data->{'secondName'} = shift;
}

################################################
## Other Methods                              ##
################################################

sub printall(){
    my $data = shift;
    $\ = "\n";
    print "FirstName: ". $data->{'firstName'} ."\n";
    print "SecondName: ". $data->{'secondName'} ."\n";
}
1;

################################################
## Package : Coder                            ##
################################################

package Coder;
@ISA = qw( Person );
use strict;
use warnings;

################################################
## Constructor                                ##
################################################
sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = {};

    bless $self, $class;
    my $superFirstName = shift;
    my $superSecondName = shift;

    print "new superfirstname "  .$superFirstName;
    print "new supersecondname " .$superSecondName; 

    $self->{'language'} = shift; #i.e. Java 
    $self->{'experience'} = shift;  #number of years

    #$self = $self->SUPER::new($superFirstName, $superSecondName); 
    Person->new($superFirstName, $superSecondName);
    return $self;
}

################################################
## Getter Methods                            ##
################################################

sub getLanguage(){
  my $data = shift;
  return $data->{'language'};
}

sub getExperience(){
  my $data = shift;
  return $data->{'experience'};
}

################################################
## Setter methods                            ##
################################################

sub setLanguage($){
  my $data = shift;
  $data->{'language'} = shift;
}

sub setExperience($){
  my $data = shift;
  $data->{'experience'} = shift;
}

################################################
## Other Methods                              ##
################################################

sub printall(){
    my $data = shift;
    $\ = "\n";

    print "Experience: " . $data->{'experience'};
    print "Language: " . $data->{'language'};

    $data->SUPER::printall();

}
1;


################################################
## Package : Main                            ##
################################################
package main;

my $developer = Coder->new("John","Smith","Perl","2");

$developer->printall();
```

Comment: Please format your code using the binary button above the editor window, or indent all the code by four spaces.

Comment: Prototypes (the `()` and `($)` after your function names) are useless when applied to methods.  They only apply to bareword function calls (`myfunc(1234);` and not `$obj->mymethod(1234)`)

Comment: and shouldn't be used even then, mostly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are not doing anything with the `Person->new` return. So it just creates a *whole* other `Person` object, and `Coder` skates off happily.

What you want to do is

```
my $self = $class->SUPER::new( $superFirstName, $superSecondName );
```

And have `Person` bless it into whatever class you pass it--as it does. Then after creating `$self` the `SUPER` way, you want to add to it the fields you need.

So it should look something like:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $superFirstName = shift;
    my $superSecondName = shift;
    print "new superfirstname "  .$superFirstName;
    print "new supersecondname " .$superSecondName; 

    my $self = $class->SUPER::new( $superFirstName, $superSecondName );
    # OR
    # $self = $class->Person::new( $superFirstName, $superSecondName );

    $self->{language}   = shift; #i.e. Java 
    $self->{experience} = shift;  #number of years

    return $self;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! 
 $self = $class->Person::new( $superFirstName, $superSecondName );
I used this line and it did the job, many thanks, I wish I had a better reputation to give you points.

Answer (score 3):

If you are intending that Coder inherits from Person, you are constructing it
incorrectly. For example, in Coder's constructor, you are creating a new Person object and then
throwing it away.  This would be a much better (and more standard) way of
constructing a Coder object that inherits from Person (see [perldoc
perltoot](http://perldoc.perl.org/perltoot.html)):

```
sub new
{
    my $class = shift;
    my $this = $class->SUPER::new(shift, shift);

    # add on extra fields, now at the head of @_...

    bless $this, $class;
    return $this;
}
```

There are also many improvements you could make:

- missing `use strict; use warnings;` in Person
- `use parent 'Person';` rather than manipulating @ISA
- function prototypes are rarely a good idea (only use them if you *know* you need them, and this is *never* true when writing an object-oriented class where functions will be called as methods)
- you can automatically generate accessors and mutators with [Class::Accessor](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Class::Accessor), rather than writing a lot of duplicated boilerplate

Also, although I'm not sure you're ready (you should understand the
fundamentals of Perl OO construction first), you can skip writing almost all
this code by using [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose):

```
package Person;
use Moose;
has [qw(firstName secondName)] => (
    is => 'rw', isa => 'Str',
);
no Moose;
__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
1;

package Coder;
use Moose;
extends 'Person';
has [qw(language experience)] => (
    is => 'rw', isa => 'Str',
);
no Moose;
__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
1;
```

Comment: can you explain the "no Moose"?

Comment: @ysth it unimports the moose sugar functions (like `has`, `extends`, `with`, `before`/`after`/`around` etc.) so that no one can accidentally call `Yourclass->has(...)` later on (or so that they don't accidentally shadow similarly-named methods from your superclasses, which would be even worse). [namespace::autoclean](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/namespace::autoclean) is another way of dealing with the situation.

Answer (score 2):

The constructor for `Coder` doesn't make sense; you're calling `Person->new` and then *throwing away* the result. Here's a more useful pattern:

```
package Coder;

sub new {
  my $class = shift;

  my $self = $class->SUPER::new(shift, shift); # firstname, lastname

  $self->{language} = shift;
  $self->{experience} = shift;

  $self;
}
```

Yes, the `Person` constructor will bless the object into `Coder` in this case, not into `Person` -- that's the point of having the class as the first argument to `new`.

This is the minimum-changes version of your code, but I'd like to make a few suggestions beyond that:

1. Positional parameters to the constructor are a great way to make sure no one knows what's going on. I'd suggest typing it as `Person->new(first_name => "Joe", last_name => "Random")` etc.
2. You might be better off forgetting all of this drudge work and using [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Moose) :)